# In Magento 1.5, how do I set orders to be shown as Complete once Invoice, Shipping and Payment are all in place?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, status, magento-1.5

In Magento 1.4.0.1 and earlier our invoices would show as Processing until we had created an invoice, packing slip and authorised payment.  At that point it would show Complete as all items were in place.

Since the upgrade to 1.5.1 even when I create invoice, packing slip and capture payment the process is still marked as Processing when it should now move to Paid.

Has anybody else seen this? How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Simon

Comment: what payment method are you using?

Comment: I'm using both Realex and also an Amazon extension from Camiloo (in which orders come in Paid but with no invoice or shipping slip).  Regardless of which of these methods I use - when all 3 items (invoice, shipping, payment) are complete it doesn't change status.

Comment: do you have logging enabled?  Anything in system.log or exception.log?

Comment: Hey - there is nothing related to either module when payment is taken.

Comment: do you have any custom Order Status states in System>Order Statuses? Check that the Complete status is assigned correctly there.

Comment: All standard statuses - really frustrating! It's something that must have changed between 1.4.0.1 and 1.5.1 as that's what I upgraded to last week.

Answer (score 1):

@Jonathan Day has it - they re-wrote this part and there are new 'Order Statuses' options in your system menu. These work fine out the box on a fresh 1.5 install with the payment gateways and 'noddy' payment methods, e.g. 'send in a cheque'.

You might want to try backing everything up, moving your public_html and installing a new Magento 1.6 RC1 build to see if it works on a 'fresh install on old db' rather than a Magento Connect upgrade. If it does work then move your themes and modules back across.

Comment: Hi - I did a fresh install on old DB as I basically hooked up 1.5.1 and moved themes/modules and pointed that at the old DB.

Comment: useful info @mathew. @simonyoung maybe try using one of the Out Of The Box Magento payment methods on your fresh 1.5.1 install. Its possible that those third-party modules aren't compatible with 1.5.1